# Django model managers -object is not callable

Tags: django

First time I am using the managers in django model  so problem can be very basic

I try to calculate totals for my Materials model 
those totals are stored in different tables like   Inventory , PO, SO

For this reason I decided to do the aggregations inside Material model  manager

```
class MaterialInventoryManager(models.Manager):
    def total_active_inventory(self):
        return self.get_query_set().annotate(total_inventory=Sum('inventory__quantity')).filter(is_active = True)


class Material(models.Model):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    materialuom = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                              choices=UOM_CHOICES)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    total_inventory =  MaterialInventoryManager()
    objects = MaterialInventoryManager()


@with_author 
class Inventory(models.Model): 
    material =  models.OneToOneField('item.Material',null=True, blank=True)
    # material_UOM =  models.OneToOneField('item.UOM_BINUOM',null=True, blank=True)
    warehouse_Bin =  models.ForeignKey(WarehouseBin)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    quantity =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

And when I execute from shell Material.total_inventory()
I am getting 
[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typo, it's `self.get_queryset()` not `self.get_query_set()`.

Django doc about [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset).